# xpath query on id //*[@id="page"] returns two elements

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying to scrap the site [ketabejam.ir](http://ketabejam.ir/index.php?cPath=18_45_46&sort=name%7Casc&filter=14&page=2) 
I'm using python3.4.1 and for parsing I use lxml 3.4.1

by the way I parsed it with lxml.html.fromstring method 
when I load the document on my interpreter and ask for following query to get number of pages , so I can handle  pagination:

```
s = doc.xpath("//*[@id='page']")
```

surprisingly I get the result:

```
>>>len(s) == 2
True
```

I got the address of the element from firebug's minimal xpath, 
when I choose normal xpath , the query run smoothly

 
Is it a bug, or I'm doing something wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the page source for the page you linked, there are exactly two elements with that `id` in the page. Most probably the one of the top of the table, and the other one of the bottom of the table.

The copy `minimal` xpath version of firebug works based on the `id` of the element. It is only available for elements that have an `id` tag and it creates an xpath in the format -

```
//*[@id="elementID"]
```

Which is what you are getting.

Ideally, in every html page , there should only be one element with a particular `id` , that is `id` should be unique across the page. And seem like `firebug`'s minimal xpath depends on that.

In your context, I think both elements return the same link, so you can use either to continue your scraping. Or as you indicated , you can use the normal xpath for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can work around this in general by always doing something like:

```
s = doc.xpath("(//*[@id='page'])[1]")
```

...if you know you really just want the first node that matches, and can safely ignore any subsequent ones (which seems like a safe bet in this case).